# Уменьшение папки bitrix

Tags: windows, битрикс, оптимизация, хостинг, веб-сайт

Делаю резервное копирование собственного сайта technocourse.ru в битриксе. В нем есть папка bitrix, занимающая 1,4 Гб. Каким образом можно уменьшить размер папки bitrix? Или как еще можно уменьшить размер сайта, потому что как я понимаю не один хостинг не выдержит такого размера)? На скриншоте приведен размер с учетом резервной копии (но и 1,4 ГБ достаточно большой размер данных для сайта)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Битрикс изначально не создан для размещения на хостингах, для него нужно VPS/VDS. В вашем случае вы можете отказаться от бэкапа ядра в настройках создания бэкапа, т.к. папка bitrix - это ядро. В целом если вы не правите код сайта, то вы ничем не рискуете в данном случае. Но вообще лучше рассмотрите вариант использования дешевой VPS.